# Identifying the number of unique entries in a column of csv and removing if <=1

Tags: bash, bigdata

very new to Bash so please no hate. I would like to learn how to count the number of unique values in a column of data entries within a csv file and remove it entirely if the the number is <= 1.
Something similar to this which identifies the empty columns
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Y7Y.png)

Okay so here is an example of what I'm talking about.
If the csv file was something like:

A, B, C, D .... (many columns)

1, 7, x, l

1, 3, , d

1, 2, , g

1, 6, , b

1, 8, x, j

1, 9, , y

(many rows)

The algorithm following something similar in the snap accompanying it, would remove columns A and C since they have one value or less.

Comment: Can you post an extract of the csv file.

Comment: Hi, The csv file is a bit of a mess, there's the headers and first two entries

Comment: Could you maybe edit the post again to redact some of the CSV file, in particular removing the "adserver" entries and changing the URLs to something innocuous like www.fakedomain.com/nosuchfolder/nosuchpage/42? In its current form, it looks a bit like spam and might get wrongly flagged as such.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I just threw in a sample instead and what the expected output would be. I assume that the code would apply to huge datasets too.

Comment: Feel free to ignore this, but I would recommend chucking this table into a database (SQLite would be ideal for some quick cleanup). SQL is a very powerful data processor.

Comment: Column C has *two* distinct values, one of which is the empty string (or space, if the file is taken literally).

Comment: Okay yes, so in this case, I have been forced to do this in bash, and only bash. Otherwise I would have take this to python. The case would be that empty is not a considered a unique value